# how to write a custom protocol for multiple line input into mrJobs

Tags: python, multiline, mrjob

I'm trying to use mrJobs with a csv file. The problem is the csv file has input spanned over multiple lines.

Searching through the mrJob documentation, I think I need to write a custom protocol to handle the input.

I tried to write my own protocol below, `multiLineCsvInputProtocol`, but I am already getting an error:  `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Not going to lie in that I think I am over my head here.

Basically each new row of data in the multi-line csv file starts with a datestring. I want to read input line by line, spit each line on the commas, store the values in a list, and whenever a new line starts with a datestring, I want to `yield` the entire list to the first mapper.

(That or find some other better way to read multi-line csv input)

Can anyone help me get passed this error?

```
import csv
import mapreduce as mr
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
from mrjob import protocol

class multiLineCsvInputProtocol(object):
    def read(self, line):
        key, val = enumerate(line.split(',', 1))
        return key, val


class someTask(MRJob):

  INPUT_PROTOCOL = multiLineCsvInputProtocol

  def mapper1(self,_, row):
    yield (row, 1 )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRFindReciprocal.run()
```

Comment: You should add some example csv data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#writing-custom-protocols) of the `mrjob`, the **line** parameter of the **read** function has the type of **bytestring**, you are most likely getting that error because you are **split**-ting by `','` which is an **str**:

> Writing custom protocols
>
> A protocol is an object with methods read(self, line) and write(self,
> key, value). The read() method takes a bytestring and returns a
> 2-tuple of decoded objects, and write() takes the key and value and
> returns bytes to be passed back to Hadoop Streaming or as output.

Possible solutions:

1. You can try splitting by `b','`, which is a **bytestring**
2. You can decode the **line** before the splitting, like this: `line.decode().split(',', 1)`
   *(it's probably a good idea to specify the encoding)*